# duvida instalar chatterbot no windows

Tags: python

Estou tentando instalar o chatterbot via pip install chatterbot, porem está dando o erro abaixo, o que pode ser?

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip3 install chatterbot
Collecting chatterbot
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/0e/dac0d82f34f86bf509c
f5ef3e2dfc5aa7d444bd843a2330ceb7d854f84f2/ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting sqlalchemy<1.3,>=1.2 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/67/d07cf7ac7e6dd0bc55b
a62816753f86d7c558107104ca915e730c9ec2512/SQLAlchemy-1.2.19.tar.gz
Collecting nltk<4.0,>=3.2 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/56/90178929712ce427eba
d179f8dc46c8deef4e89d4c853092bee1efd57d05/nltk-3.4.1.zip
Collecting pint>=0.8.1 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/9d/bf177ebbc57d25e9e29
6addc14a1303d1e34d7964af5df428a8332349c42/Pint-0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/68/d87d9b36af36f44254a
8d512cbfc48369103a3b9e474be9bdfe536abfc45/python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any
.whl
Collecting mathparse<0.2,>=0.1 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/e5/4910fb85950cb960fcf
3f5aabe1c8e55f5c9201788a1c1302b570a7e1f84/mathparse-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1 (from chatterbot)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/f3/eb5aece989ecca541c4
b5a439cb8a86fe5254b1521925b547609fb3aaf64/spacy-2.1.3.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\python37\python.exe' 'c:\python37\lib\
site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\ADMRE
D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-putlvsmp\overlay' --no-warn-script-location
 --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptool
s 'wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'm
urmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.0.0.dev6:
  ERROR: Collecting setuptools
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/51/f45cea425fd5cb0b0
380f5b0f048ebc1da5b417e48d304838c02d6288a1e/setuptools-41.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.w
hl
  Collecting wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/ba/a4702cbb6a3a48523
9fbe9525443446203f00771af9ac000fa3ef2788201/wheel-0.33.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/4a/8fcaa2e03b9b97f26
da39e47e1cfa008ff04037b41c35b178539f6245de4/Cython-0.29.7-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/cb/4ff546a491f764f67
284572d25c57927e3f17103adf979bc99d90128f3eb/cymem-2.0.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/52/ef641ebb40e287b95
e9742e7f3120dca0350d92b3d0ef050e5133acf8931/preshed-2.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
  Collecting thinc==7.0.0.dev6
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/4b/c38b5144cf167c4f5
2288517436ccafefe9dc01b8d1c190e18a6b154cd4a/tqdm-4.31.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/75/9ac63977cbca68e17
406a53a8c573a925a16771800be47a73f18c838f3fb/numpy-1.16.3-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.5 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
  Collecting thinc-gpu-ops<0.1.0,>=0.0.1 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/c1/d76ccdd12c716be79
162d934fe7de4ac8a318b9302864716dde940641a79/wasabi-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting six<2.0.0,>=1.10.0 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fec
fe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/9b/62c60d2f5bc135d2a
a1d8c8a86aaf84edb719a59c7f11a4316259e61a298/plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/9e/84a83616cbe5daa94
909da38b780e93bf566dc2113c3dc35d7b4cad52f63/blis-0.2.4.tar.gz
  Collecting wrapt<1.11.0,>=1.10.0 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
  Building wheels for collected packages: blis
    Building wheel for blis (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for blis (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import s
etuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMRED~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip
-install-im7vrekv\\blis\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(co
mpile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\ADMRED~1\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-a18xpoh7' --python-tag cp37:
    ERROR: BLIS_COMPILER? None
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
    copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
    copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
    copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
    copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
    copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
    copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
    copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
    running build_ext
    error: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
    msvc
    py_compiler msvc
    {'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40
;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;4
2:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:
*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=0
1;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;
31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=0
1;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.w
ar=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31
:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01
;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:
*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01
;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.
pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01
;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nu
v=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:
*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;3
5:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=
00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*
.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00
;36:', 'HOSTTYPE': 'x86_64', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LANG': 'C.
UTF-8', 'OLDPWD': '/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', 'VIRTUAL_ENV': '/home/matt/repo
s/cython-blis/env3.6', 'USER': 'matt', 'PWD': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis', 'H
OME': '/home/matt', 'NAME': 'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/local/shar
e:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'TERM': 'xterm-256co
lor', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LOGNAME': 'matt', 'PATH': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env
3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/
bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/ven
dor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/cone
mu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/mnt
/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Ma
nagement Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management E
ngine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/Syst
em32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x
86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/I
ntel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(
R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Manageme
nt Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program File
s/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporatio
n/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/m
nt/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Window
s/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/Sy
stem32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Micro
soft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:
/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/Virt
ualBox', 'PS1': '(env3.6) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_c
hroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00
m\\]\\$ ', 'VAGRANT_HOME': '/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/les
spipe %s', '_': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin/python'}
    clang -c C:\Users\ADMRED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-im7vrekv\blis\blis
\_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o C:\Users\ADMRED~1\AppData\Lo
cal\Temp\tmp2cu8866c\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o -O2 -funroll-all-loops -std=c99 -
D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBR
ARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\frame\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m\
-I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\ADMRED~1\AppData\Local\T
emp\pip-install-im7vrekv\blis\blis\_src\include\windows-x86_64
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
    Running setup.py clean for blis
  Failed to build blis
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, cymem, preshed, murm
urhash, tqdm, numpy, srsly, thinc-gpu-ops, wasabi, six, plac, blis, wrapt, thinc

    Running setup.py install for blis: started
      Running setup.py install for blis: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import
 setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMRED~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\p
ip-install-im7vrekv\\blis\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', ope
n)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(
compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ADMRED~1\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\pip-record-10auke9u\install-record.txt' --single-version-extern
ally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\ADMRED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-putlvs
mp\overlay' --compile:
      ERROR: BLIS_COMPILER? None
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
      copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
      copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
      copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis\tests
      copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
      copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
      copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
      copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\blis
      running build_ext
      error: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
      msvc
      py_compiler msvc
      {'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=
40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34
;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;3
1:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo
=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=0
1;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz
=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*
.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;
31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=
01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;3
5:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=
01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:
*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=
01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.
nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;3
5:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01
;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.fla
c=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36
:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=
00;36:', 'HOSTTYPE': 'x86_64', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LANG': '
C.UTF-8', 'OLDPWD': '/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', 'VIRTUAL_ENV': '/home/matt/re
pos/cython-blis/env3.6', 'USER': 'matt', 'PWD': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis',
'HOME': '/home/matt', 'NAME': 'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/local/sh
are:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'TERM': 'xterm-256
color', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LOGNAME': 'matt', 'PATH': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/e
nv3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/us
r/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/v
endor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/co
nemu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/m
nt/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R)
Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management
 Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/Sy
stem32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files
(x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel
/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Inte
l(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Manage
ment Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Fi
les/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporat
ion/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:
/mnt/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Wind
ows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/
System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Mic
rosoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bi
n:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/Vi
rtualBox', 'PS1': '(env3.6) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian
_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[
00m\\]\\$ ', 'VAGRANT_HOME': '/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/l
esspipe %s', '_': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin/python'}
      clang -c C:\Users\ADMRED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-im7vrekv\blis\bl
is\_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o C:\Users\ADMRED~1\AppData\
Local\Temp\tmppdtuv9ti\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o -O2 -funroll-all-loops -std=c99
 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LI
BRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\frame\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m
\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\ADMRED~1\AppData\Local
\Temp\pip-install-im7vrekv\blis\blis\_src\include\windows-x86_64
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command "'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__
file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ADMRED~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-im7vrekv\\bli
s\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read
().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__,
'"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ADMRED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-rec
ord-10auke9u\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C
:\Users\ADMRED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-putlvsmp\overlay' --compile" f
ailed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ADMRED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-im7v
rekv\blis\
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\python37\python.exe' 'c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip' ins
tall --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\ADMRED~1\AppData\Local\Temp
\pip-build-env-putlvsmp\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --
only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.
0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1
.0' thinc==7.0.0.dev6" failed with error code 1 in None
```

Comment: Se for Python 3, tenta pip3

Comment: continuou com mesmos erros

Comment: Essa é a mensagem de erro completa? Parece que falta coisa aí.

Comment: editei com a completa

Answer (score 1):

O instalador não encontrou uma versão binária, já compilada, de um dos módulos que é pré-requisito do Chatterbot, e foi tentar compilar o mesmo localmente. Nesse ponto, ele não encontrou as ferramentas e ambiente necessários para compilação de código nativo - o compilador MSVC (e possivelmente outras ferramentas se ele encontrar isso).

Olhando por cima, o pacote que falhou parece ter sido o "python-blis" - esse aqui: https://pypi.org/project/blis/ -

Tente achar e instalar uma versão pré-compilada disso para a sua combinação de versão do Python + Windows (32 ou 64bit) - e possivelmente o restante da instalação do chatterbot vai funcionar (basta repetir o pip install).

Comece por tentar simplesmente com "pip install blis" - o erro deve acontecer de novo, mas se passar, repita o "pip install chaterbot" na sequência.

Se não achar uma forma de instalar o Python blis, vai precisar configurar um ambiente de build para compilar código nativo na sua máquina. - talvez as dicas aqui sejam o suficiente: https://cs.mcgill.ca/~mxia3/2017/04/05/Compiling-Python-package-with-C-extension-on-Windows-10-and-Visual-Studio-2017/

Comment: o problema na realidade era a versão do python, instalei 64bits e foi